# grid-template-columns is not working

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I have one block, `display: grid`.

According to the idea, the first element should be stretched to 2 columns and 2 rows, the others occupy one cell each.

But the `grid-template-columns` property does not work for me, whatever value I put there, the content does not move.

Now the first element got into the first cell only, got out of bounds, but did not stretch on two columns and two rows.

Where is my issue?

What I need:

[image: picture]

```css
.exclusive-content {
  display: grid;
  grid: 270px 270px / repeat(4, 270px);
  justify-content: center;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.exclusive-content img {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.exclusive-content a:first-child {
  width: 540px;
  height: 540px;
  grid-template-columns: 1 / 3;
  grid-template-rows: 1 / 3
}

.exclusive-content a:nth-child(2) {
  grid-template-columns: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="exclusive-content">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://anti-naruto.ru/img/product-1-lg.jpg" alt="1"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://anti-naruto.ru/img/product-2-sm.jpg" alt="2"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://anti-naruto.ru/img/product-3-sm.jpg" alt="3"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://anti-naruto.ru/img/product-4-sm.jpg" alt="4"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://anti-naruto.ru/img/product-5-sm.jpg" alt="5"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` properties on the child of the grid. These properties are used with `display: grid` on the container.

For direct child elements of the grid, use [grid-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) and [grid-row](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row).

```css
.exclusive-content {
  display: grid;
  grid: 270px 270px / repeat(4, 270px);
  justify-content: center;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.exclusive-content img {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.exclusive-content a:first-child {
  width: 540px;
  height: 540px;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3
}

.exclusive-content a:nth-child(2) {
  grid-template-columns: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="exclusive-content">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://anti-naruto.ru/img/product-1-lg.jpg" alt="1"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://anti-naruto.ru/img/product-2-sm.jpg" alt="2"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://anti-naruto.ru/img/product-3-sm.jpg" alt="3"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://anti-naruto.ru/img/product-4-sm.jpg" alt="4"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://anti-naruto.ru/img/product-5-sm.jpg" alt="5"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are applying the [**`grid-template-columns`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing) property to grid items. This is a grid container property. It will be ignored on grid items (unless they are also grid containers).

Instead use the [**`grid-column`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#placement-shorthands) and [**`grid-row`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#placement-shorthands) properties, which apply to grid items.

```css
.exclusive-content {
  display: grid;
  grid: 270px 270px / repeat(4, 270px);
  justify-content: center;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.exclusive-content img {
  /* background-size: cover; (applies only to background images; not what you have) */
  /* background-position: center; (same as above; does nothing here) */
  width: 100%; /* new */
}

.exclusive-content a:first-child {
  /* width: 540px; (not necessary; size controlled at grid container level)  */
  /* height: 540px; (same as above) */
  grid-column: 1 / 3; /* adjustment */
  grid-row: 1 / 3;    /* adjustment */
}

.exclusive-content a:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 3;     /* adjustment */
}
```

```html
<div class="exclusive-content">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://anti-naruto.ru/img/product-1-lg.jpg" alt="1"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://anti-naruto.ru/img/product-2-sm.jpg" alt="2"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://anti-naruto.ru/img/product-3-sm.jpg" alt="3"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://anti-naruto.ru/img/product-4-sm.jpg" alt="4"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://anti-naruto.ru/img/product-5-sm.jpg" alt="5"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

...see here [MDN CSS grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns)

the container in which you are defining the rows and columns are written like this
`grid-template- : 30% 70% (variety of different ways you can define)`
then on the actual cell you define which row and column it sits in `grid-row: 1/3` and `grid-column: 2/3`

See my [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/wexusefefi/edit?html,css,output) example. (If your first image was wider it would fit the entire row...)

Comment: i'm so sorry. I forgot to add reference picture. That is i.stack.imgur.com/j5EW2.png
How perfectly to write my CSS?

Comment: @Michael_B What i meant is that he was applying `grid-template-___` on classes that were most likely meant to be cells within the container grid instead of defining template row/col on the container itself, I've edited my answer.